# XmlSerializer doesn't fill in values

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, xml-serialization

I created classes from a DTD (over XSD and xsd.exe) for my C# project, so I could easily deserialize them into a model class in my code.

This is roughly how I do it:

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(tipsfile.FullName, readerSettings);

XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "Tips";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tips), xRoot);
Tips tips = (Tips)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

reader.Close();
```

But, upon inspection of `tips`, I see that it holds no values at all from the original XML file. Also, I tried setting a breakpoint on the `set`-Body of a property of `Tips`, and it is never reached, although I know for sure that it has a value in the original XML file.

Why is the file not correctly deserialized into the class? Is something missing in my code?

**Edit:** Here is the Tips.cs file, which was auto-generated from the XSD

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MyNs.Model
{
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/caravan_1")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/caravan_1", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Tips
    {
        private Chapter[] chapterField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Chapter")]
        public Chapter[] Chapter
        {
            get
            {
                return this.chapterField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.chapterField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/caravan_1")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/caravan_1", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Chapter
    {
        private string headingField;
        private CarType[] carTypesField;
        private Section[] sectionField;
        private string countryField;
        private string languageField;

        public string Heading
        {
            get
            {
                return this.headingField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.headingField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("CarType", IsNullable = false)]
        public CarType[] CarTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.carTypesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.carTypesField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Section")]
        public Section[] Section
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sectionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sectionField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Country
        {
            get
            {
                return this.countryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.countryField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Language
        {
            get
            {
                return this.languageField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.languageField = value;
            }
        }
    }
     [... and so on ...]
```

And a sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Tips SYSTEM "caravan_1.dtd">
<Tips>
    <Chapter Country="dafghagt" Language="de">
        <Heading>fgagasgargaergarg</Heading>        
        <Section id="1">
            <Heading>afdhwr6u5taehtaqh5</Heading>
            <SubSection id="1">
                <Heading>46k46kw6jhadfgadfha</Heading>              
                <Table>
                    <Row id="1">
                        <Heading>sgjsfgjsgfh443q572q356</Heading>
                        <Items>
                            <Item car="motor1" id="1">
                                <BodyText color="red">130*</BodyText>
                                <Subscript>3</Subscript>
                            </Item>
                        </Items>
                    </Row>
                </Table>
            </SubSection>
        </Section>
    </Chapter>
</Tips>
```

Comment: have you declared the elements inside tips as serializable?`using system.xml.serialization` `[XMLelement]`

Comment: They are all mapped accordingly - the generator did that quite fine from the XSD

Comment: Ah I apologize, i read the question incorrectly, I've added an answer that shows how I handle my deserialization.. its a little different so maybe it could solve your problem

Comment: I edited my question and added the Model and a sample XML, maybe it helps.

Comment: It may be failing as it doesn't know what type Chapter and Section are (see extra types in my answer, its a type array). have you tried surrounding your deserialize in a `trycatch(exception ex)messagebox.show(ex.message);`?

Comment: I will check that - but exceptions are not thrown anywhere in deserialize, otherwise I would have posted those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the problem is *namespaces*. Because my XML has no root namespace:

```
<Tips>
```

but the definition of my Model contained one:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/caravan_1", IsNullable = false)]
```

the Serializer didn't match any elements together. When removing the namespace attribute, it worked fine.

So now, I reworked the complete model and excluded any attributes that were not absolutely necessary (as it turns out, all but one were), so now every Property has just one Attribute: `XmlElement` and consorts.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MyNs.Model
{
    [XmlRoot("Tips")]
    public partial class Tips
    {
        [XmlElement("Chapter")]
        public Chapter[] Chapter { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Chapter")]
    public partial class Chapter
    {
        [XmlElement("Heading")]
        public string Heading { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CarType")]
        public CarType[] CarTypes { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Section")]
        public Section[] Section { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
    [... and so on ...]
```

With a simple deserialization it works just fine now:

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse };
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tips));

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fromXmlFile.FullName, readerSettings))
{
    Tips tips = (Tips)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    return tips;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fileName, false);
        XmlTextReader xmlw = new XmlTextReader(sw);
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(
            type,
            GetOverrides(),
            extraTypes,
            null,
            null);

        object o = writer.Deserialize(xmlw);
```

As per my comment, get overrides is just a method that contains something similar to your xml root attribute, I can show you this too if necessary

EDIT:
an example of extra types

```
    public Type[] GetTypes()
    {
        return new Type[] { typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2)};
    }
```

EDIT2: get overrides returns (Note this is untested)

```
XmlAttributes attribs = new XmlAttributes();
//attribs.XmlRoot - can edit root here (instead of xmlrootattribute)
attribs.XmlElements.Add(myAttribute);

XmlAttributeOverrides myOverride = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
myOverride.Add(typeof(Tips), "Tips", attribs);
return myOverride
```

Comment: That doesn't really change anything, does it? It only wraps the reader around. Anyway, I edited my question and added the Model and a sample XML, maybe it helps.

Comment: It uses the extra types parameter which is a `Type` array, used to include any of your own classes

Comment: So in there I would include every class from my Model?

Comment: Could you show what GetOverrides returns? I'm not sure what I should do there.

Comment: are you including the type of `chapter[]` and `chapter`? (I've not had to do this before so not sure about this)

Comment: I have had to do this with a List<> and to do that I needed to put my list in a wrapper class (a class that just contains a list)

Answer (score 1):

Your object may not be identical to the xml model. In that case, you need map the properties of your class to the xml fields. I am giving you a quick example I had in one of my projects which may give you bit more information.

```
namespace DatabaseModel
{
    [Description("Represents the selected nodes in the Coverage pane")]
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRootAttribute("XmlCoverage", Namespace = "GISManager", IsNullable = false)]
    public class TXmlCoverage : IXmlPolygon
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "sbets"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "sbet")]
        public List SbetsSelected { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "sdcs"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "sdc")]
        public List SdcsSelected { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "area")]
        public Boolean IsAreaSelected { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "fpath")]
        public Boolean IsFlightPathSelected { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "fpoly")]
        public Boolean IsFlightPolySelected { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "mpoly")]
        public Boolean IsMinePolySelected { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "bldg")]
        public Boolean IsBuildingsSelected { get; set; }
        [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "hgt")]
        public Boolean IsHeightSelected { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore()]
        public Boolean ArePolygonsSelected { get { return IsMinePolySelected && IsBuildingsSelected && IsHeightSelected; } }
```

```
    public TXmlCoverage()
    {
        SbetsSelected = new List<String>();
        SdcsSelected = new List<String>();
        IsAreaSelected = false;
        IsFlightPathSelected = false;
        IsFlightPolySelected = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think that my Model is any different, because I created it automatically from the corresponding XSD/DTD - So, if my model were wrong, the generation process would be wrong. Anyway, I checked and all the Properties of my Model were correctly mapped to existing XML tags - including tag names (case-sensitive)

Comment: I edited my question and added the Model and a sample XML, maybe it helps.